# why is different so file offset in android dynamic debuging

Tags: android, security, static-libraries

I am doing a static analysis and dynamic analysis. 
And I get the offset of a specific function in so file. but the offset is not correct in IDA(dynamic debugging). 
How to get real address in static analysis?
and why is different in static analysis and dynamic analysis?

apk file have two version arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a.
so I used "adb pull" and compare with the so files.
armeabi-v7a had the same address as obtained by adb pull.
so I get the offset in armeabi-v7a

Answer (score 0):

You will see different address because the base address of the so module at the runtime can be different everytime wherever the operating system finds place to put it.
And then based on that (base + function offset) will give you the function address at the runtime.

During static analysis you may have set the (or the default) setting is such that the base address is zero. If you have the feature to rebase your so module in your static analyser , you can do that to rebase it to your runtime address.

Comment: I could find base address using frida. And I found function's address with base address.